# сумма свойств объектов в массиве

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Итак, имеем массив, элементами которого  являются объекты

```js
var obj = [ 
    { model : 'a1',
      speed : 20,
      locate : "aa"
     },
     
    { model : 'a2',
      speed : 30,
      locate : "bb"
     },
     
     { model : 'a3',
      speed : 15,
      locate : "bc"
     },
     
     
    { model : 'a4',
      speed : 35,
      locate : "cd"
     },
     
];
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно   получить сумму всех  свойств speed каждого  объекта, причем объектов внутри массива может быть случайное кол-во.

Comment: Так получайте, голубчик, получайте! А от нас чего хотите?

Comment: Приведите пример Вашего кода.

Comment: дада, вот именно, что нужна помощь. Пока только  разобрался как сделать через присвоение переменным элементов массива и далее банально  суммирования переменных, но это же не гуд, господа. 
Я честно  прогуглил 2 часа и получить ответ сам не смог .

Comment: И как же Вы искали? Я по первой ссылке в гугле нашёл ответ.

Comment: Спасибо за приведенную ссылку, которая мне может помочь найти ответ на мой вопрос. К сожалению, я нашел лишь  как получить  сумму  элементов  массива  и элементов объекта отдельно, а на  текущем этапе моего  познания  js, увы,  я не могу собрать все в кучу самостоятельно. Если Вы можете, поделитесь таки ссылкой  либо задайте направление.

Comment: я нынче всем прописываю метод [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) – если надо из массива получить в итоге одно значение.

Comment: да, верно, так и нужно . Буду пробовать

Comment: Вот та ссылка - https://learn.javascript.ru/object-for-in 2 задача с решением. Но это не самое оптимизированное решение, лучше `Array.prototype.reduce` юзать. И на будущее - будь вежливее и стремись сам решить проблему. Тогда и помощники найдутся. А в форме приказа, даже без просьбы - это минусы и забвение.

Comment: спасибо. Я просто при реге читал, правила  ресурса,  где-то написано  нечто вроде "напишите Ваш вопрос максимально коротко  и понятно, не используя лишних  слов". Впредь учту , спасибо .

Comment: Слова "пожалуйста" и "помогите" трактуется как "лишние слова"? Жесть.

Comment: Да ладно уже Вам . Принят Ваш  совет. Я лишь только "за" вежливость )

Comment: Надеюсь. Спишем на непонимание правил и разойдёмся миром :) Удачи!

Answer (score 3):

Этот нехитрый пример склеивает свойства `locate` всех объектов вашей коллекции:

```js
var arr = [
  {
    model: 'a1',
    speed: 20,
    locate: "aa"
  }, {
    model: 'a2',
    speed: 30,
    locate: "bb"
  }, {
    model: 'a3',
    speed: 15,
    locate: "bc"
  }, {
    model: 'a4',
    speed: 35,
    locate: "cd"
  }
];

document.body.innerText = arr.reduce(function(p,c){return p+c.locate;},'');
```

Надеюсь, поможет сдвинуться с места и сложить скорости.

Comment: Можно и прозрачнее было бы намекнуть, тут любой догадается, где шевеление мозговой мышцой?

Comment: в собственном ответе ТС – мозговая качалка прям: пот, боль и стероиды )

Answer (score 3):

при помощи Array.prototype получилось! Спасибо  за подсказки)

```js
var arr = [ 
    { model : 'a1',
      speed : 20,
      locate : "aa"
     },
     
    { model : 'a2',
      speed : 30,
      locate : "bb"
     },
     
     { model : 'a3',
      speed : 15,
      locate : "bc"
     },
     
     
    { model : 'a4',
      speed : 35,
      locate : "cd"
     },
     
];


       
Array.prototype.sum = function (prop) {
    var total = 0
    for ( var i = 0, _len = this.length; i < _len; i++ ) {
        total += this[i][prop]
    }
    return total
}
    
console.log(arr.sum("speed"));
```

Comment: Отлично! Только расширять базовые объекты - это плохо. Так, на будущее.